# Upload file on Openshift

Tags: javascript, bash, openshift

I want to start a Nodejs application on [Openshift](http://www.openshift.com/) and because I want use persistent files (like images) I need to store them in the `OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR` directory.

I've made this action_hooks for the build phase:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

#First of all I check if the dir exists. If not I create it
if [ ! -d $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR'images' ]
then
    echo "Create "$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR'images'
    mkdir -p $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR'images'
fi

#Create symlink
echo "Create link: "$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'images -> '$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR'images'
ln -sf $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR'images' $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'images'
```

The symbolic link is created, but the index.html can't access to the uploaded file

This is my (dumb) `index.html` test page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="image_container"/>
        <div id="button_container"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var loaded = false
            var debug = false
            var clickAction = function() {
                if (debug) {
                    alert(process.env.OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR)
                }
                else {
                    if (!loaded) {
                        var container = document.getElementById("image_container")
                        var image = document.createElement("img")
                        image.src = "images/montagna.jpg"
                        image.id = "img001"
                        container.appendChild(image)
                        loaded = true
                    }
                    else {
                        var container = document.getElementById("image_container")
                        var image = document.getElementById("img001")
                        container.removeChild(image)
                        loaded = false
                    }
                }
            }
            window.onload = function() {
                var container = document.getElementById("button_container")
                var button = document.createElement("input")
                button.type = "button"
                button.name = "button1"
                button.value = "clickme"
                button.setAttribute("onclick", "clickAction()")
                container.appendChild(button)
            };

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I click on the button I receive a 404 error from the server ([this](http://testdeploy-gbenv.rhcloud.com/) is the link to the application).

Note that I've uploaded the file via SFTP (with Filezilla) inside the `~/app-root/data/images` directory of the application, and the symlink seems to work because I can see the image also from `~/app-root/repo/images`.

Comment: Yes! I'm totally new on web development and in particular with Nodejs. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is using [app.use()](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use).

```
app.use('/images', express.static(process.env.OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR+'/images'));
```